# Returning local variable from a function

Tags: c, function, return, local-variables

In the following code, I return a pointer to a `char` array that is created locally inside the function. Therefore When the return value is assigned to `y`, it should all be garbage. This seems to hold true when I print `%10s` or `%100s`. But when I print `%1000s`, I get an output that seems to confound me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* get()
{
  char x[1000] ;

  int i = 0;
  for(; i < 999; ++i)
  {
    x[i] = 'A';
  }

  x[999] = '\0';

  printf("%1000s\n",x);

  return x;
  }

  int main()
  {
    char* y = get();
    printf("Going to print\n");
    printf("%1000s\n",y);
  }
```

The output is 
[image]

Is it a coincidence that the `main()` function is accessing the same memory location that was used to create the local function char array or is it something more concrete?

Comment: Any assumptions you make upon invoking undefined behavior are meaningless. That is the very nature of undefined behavior; there is *no definition*. Therefore, the very premise you started with "it should all be garbage" is itself grasping a leap of faith. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Comment: Why not, `char x[1000] = {0};` then declare `char *get (char *x)` and finally call with `char *y = get (x);`

Answer (score 2):

See, once you *use* the return value of `get()`, you're facing [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After that, nothing is guranteed.

In other words, the output of `printf("%1000s\n",y);`<sup>##</sup> statement cannot be *justified*. It *is*, what *it is*. Undefined.

FWIW, once the `get()`function has finsihed execution, the stack space allocated for that function is *destroyed* and available for usage (*if required*) by any other function. Maybe you're making *unauthorized entry* into that part of the *physical memory*, nothing certain, though.

---

<sup>## - or, `printf("%10s\n",y);` or `printf("%100s\n",y);`, whatever, wherever `y` is *accessed*.</sup>